# Static const definitions in .h vs external const in .m

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I've find it frustrating to define constants in the .h as externals and then assign the constants in the .m file.  Seems so redundant.  Is there any reason not to just define the constants in the header file?

Typical implementation would be:

```
//  Constants.h
@interface Constants : NSObject
extern NSString *const kPCFavorites;
@end
```

The implementation would then be:

```
//  Constants.m
@implementation Constants
NSString *const kPCFavorites = @"PCFavorites";
@end
```

However, I can just do this:

```
//  Constants.h
static NSString *const kPCFavorites = @"PCFavorites";
@interface Constants : NSObject
@end
```

Obviously, this last definition doesn't even need an interface or implementation so both could be left out and become:

```
//  Constants.h
static NSString *const kPCFavorites = @"PCFavorites";
```

with no .m file at all.

This seems much cleaner to me.  Why wouldn't we implement constants this way?  I've defined them both ways and I get no compile or runtime errors in XCode 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
static NSString * const kPCFavorites = @"PCFavorites";
```

declares a *variable*, not a constant.  C doesn’t actually have a way to declare a symbolic constant (besides `enum`, which only works for integers).

As a result, if you use this method, every file that `#include`s your header will have its own variable called `kPCFavorites`.  Historically, that would have meant that your program would increase in size because of all of the copies of `kPCFavourites` and the string `@"PCFavourites"`, although more modern linkers may manage to get rid of some or all of the duplication (certainly I’d expect the linker to leave you with only one copy of the string itself; whether or not it can currently get rid of the extra pointer variables I’m not sure — but it’s easy to test).

Answer (score 2):

static variables have file scope. If you compile a file which includes a header file with a static variable, that variable will exist in the compiled file. If you compile another file with the same header file, you have a second static variable and so on. If you include the header from 1000 source files, you get 1000 static variables, all with the same name.